# Simple push notification without gcm like things

Tags: android, push-notification, android-volley, android-json, server-response

I want to implement a push notification in android app without gcm like things.I want to handle all action from my side(android) .

Till now I have a json response.Which i am trying to use in push notification.and my push notification works on click event.But i have no idea **how it check or excute json response automatically(periodically)**. Here is my current code for json respone (using volley lib.).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Log tag

    int total_time = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // total one day you can change
    int peroid_time = 5000; // one hour time is assumed to make request

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static String url = "http://my_url/Service.asmx/GetNotifications";



    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Notifications> noteList = new ArrayList<Notifications>();
    private ListView listView;
    private Custom_Adapter_N adapter;
    EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_note);
        adapter = new Custom_Adapter_N(this, noteList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        new CountDownTimer(peroid_time, total_time) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // make request to web and get reponse and show notification.
                MakingWebRequest();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Tesitng the data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                //
            }
        }.start();


//        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
//        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
//        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//        pDialog.show();


        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


    }

//    //on create
//    @Override
//    public void onDestroy() {
//        super.onDestroy();
//        hidePDialog();
//    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

   public  void MakingWebRequest() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();


                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Notifications note = new Notifications();
//                                note.setNotificationId(obj.getString("NotificationId"));
//                                note.setNotification(obj.getString("Notification"));
                                String excep = obj.getString("NotificationId");
                                String message1 = obj.getString("Notification");


                                NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                Notification notify=new Notification(R.drawable.push,message1,System.currentTimeMillis());
                                PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);

                                notify = builder.setContentIntent(pending)
                                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message1))
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push).setTicker(excep).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                        .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(message1)
                                        .setContentText(message1).build();
//                notif.notify(NOTIFICATION, notify);
                                notif.notify(0, notify);

//                                String id = obj.getString("Exception");
//                                String message1 = obj.getString("Message");
//                                Toast.makeText(Notification1.this, id.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                                Toast.makeText(Notification1.this, message1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                // adding movie to movies array
//                                noteList.add(note);

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }


                    //....  you rest code
                    //       add your notification here

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        }



        )
        {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is referred as short term because its running on `UI thread`. You can do the same in `service` for `background working`.

For running it in servic look here how [**service start and works.**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm)

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int total_time = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // total one day you can change
    int peroid_time = 1000 * 60 * 60; // one hour time is assumed to make request

    // reduced the time while testing

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new CountDownTimer(peroid_time, total_time) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // make request to web and get reponse and show notification.
                MakingWebRequest();
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                //
            }
        }.start();

    }

    void MakingWebRequest() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {


                    //....  you rest code
                    //       add your notification here

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: Bro , I don't know but it's not working,Have any issue with manifest.internet and network state state permission already given

Comment: no error except this  problem reading network stats
                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null

Comment: `onTick` is getting called or not?

Comment: yes .. onTick mrthod not getting called. So what to do?

Comment: Cant help you if cant see all your code what you are doing and how you are doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120072/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-adi).

Comment: @Adi, did you get this working? If so, do you have a more complete code-base available?